# Show Excel workbook without save in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating an Excel file in an WinForm app (VS2008) in runtime. I am exporting some data into it from datagridview. After export, i would like to show this file in excel, but dont want to save anywhere. My goal is to use it as an alternative of creating many reports in crystal. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can't you just save it temporarily and then delete it programatically later?

Comment: Thanks. yes, i can. But my question is not that.

Comment: How are you creating the file though? Surely it is saved already temporarily somewhere anyway? I see no way around that so why not just manage the process yourself. Are you using the interop? Can we see your code that creates / initialises your temp file?

Comment: If you _really_ don't want to save it anywhere then you can simply create a new workbook using Interop and not save it. Obviously you won't be able to give it a filename to refer to it (I think the default is "Book1", "Book2", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interop Service, you only can make workbook application visible equals to true.

```
[workbookobject].Application.Visible = true;
```